# Unknown class exception when inflating a dialog fragment in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to create a dialog fragment. However when trying to show the fragment, I get a force close error with the stack trace hinting at an error when inflating the xml files.
Here is my xml resource file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Share on"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#24092A" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/share_dialog_facebook"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_circle_icon_blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/share_dialog_twitter"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter_circle_icon_blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/share_dialog_googleplus"
            android:src="@drawable/google_plus_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the stack trace content:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.shimba.android.ngoma.fragments.ShareDialog.onCreateDialog(ShareDialog.java:27)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:307)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.shimba.android.ngoma.fragments.ShareDialog.onCreateDialog(ShareDialog.java:27)
            at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:307)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.shimba.android.ngoma.fragments.ShareDialog.onCreateDialog(ShareDialog.java:27)
            at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:307)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

What could be causing this problem? I don't have a clue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on bitmap just scale your bitmap image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 27 of your `ShareDialog` class you are trying to load a bitmap which is causing an OutOfMemory error. Resize the image and you should be good to go.

Comment: even after resizing the images, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Note sure why I was down voted... the error is clearly in the stack trace.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, be sure to clean and hit F5 on the project to ensure the new asset was updated.